# Couchbase Java SDK subdocument mutation

Tags: couchbase-java-api

Hi Im running `couchabse server 7.1.3` docker container and trying to use the `3.3.4 couchbase java sdk` version. I am facing an issue while performing subdocument mutation using the `upsert` command.

The issue I am facing is when I use the `collection.mutateIn()` method to perform a subdocument mutation using the `upsert` command, I am expecting to get the result of the operation as a MutateInResult object. when I try to use the `MutateInResult.contentAs(0, String.class)` to see the response I get the `Index 0 is invalid` error. I see that the operation as in is successful in the DB, I can see the desired json path has the updated value.

P.S: I only have a single mutation to perform which is the upsert command.

can someone please help if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

A `MutateInResult` only has content for the result of `increment` and `decrement` mutations. In those two cases, the content is the new counter value, which you can access using `result.contentAs(index, Long.class)`.

For all other types of subdocument mutations, the result does not include any content.